# Использовать ключ в массиве в качестве @property

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

В **myObject** множество различных @property к которым нужно получить доступ, в ходе нескольких операций собирается массив ключей дальше безумие...

Вопрос, как из имеющегося массива **array** = [@"_id", @"name", @"title"] открыть @property в **myObject** которые имеют такое же название.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *_id;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * title;
```

**myObject**.name стандартный доступ, но нужно что-то вроде 
**myObject**.[**array**[0]] как-то так...

P.S. идеи allKeys были откинуты, т.к. необходимо было сохранить последовательность и обеспечить нормальный доступ с переменным внутри объекта.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У NSObject есть методы, которые позволяют читать данные прямо из переменных

https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-valueforkey?language=objc

пример:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *testString;

[self setValue:@"test value" forKey:@"testString"];
NSLog(@"result %@", [self valueForKey:@"testString"]);
```

Comment: Верно, вчера нашел ответ, спасибо за помощь!)